# $M\oplus A \cong A\oplus A$ implies $M\cong A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative unital ring and $M$ an $A$-module. Suppose that $M\oplus A \cong A\oplus A$. Then is $M\cong A$?

We have that both $M\oplus A$ and $A\oplus A$ are biproduct for $(A, A)$ and $(M, A)$, so actually short exact sequences. Further $A\oplus A$ is the free $A$-module of rank two. However I can't conclude. Maybe I have to use some extension stuff from homological theory or there are some apparent counter-examples that I'm not able to figure out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you wrote in a comment that you know about tensor products and their quotients, here is a hint. Oh, I should say first that I think this is a great problem (I used it myself when teaching a graduate algebra course) because it is a striking application of multilinear algebra when it's hard to see how to even get started using more direct tools, as far as I know.

Hint: Using exterior powers, there is a Kunneth formula 
$$
\Lambda^2(M_1 \oplus M_2) \cong \Lambda^2(M_1) \oplus (M_1 \otimes_A M_2) \oplus \Lambda^2(M_2)
$$
for any two $A$-modules $M_1$ and $M_2$. (There is a corresponding formula for higher exterior powers, but it's not needed here.) Take the second exterior power of both sides of the isomorphism $M \oplus A \cong A \oplus A$ and use the Kunneth formula. Look closely at what you have. Then take second exterior powers again and look closely at what you have.

Comment: This can (as I’m sure you know) be unwound into a very elementary direct proof, with neat formulas that seem to be pulled out of a hat. Write the map $M \oplus A \to A \oplus A$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix $\Phi$, whose left column entries are from $M^*$ (and right col from $A$). Similarly, write the inverse map as a matrix $\Psi$, with top row entries from $M$.  Now $\det \Phi$ (the usual formula) is an element of $M^*$, so a map $M \to A$; and $\det \Psi$ is an element of $M$, so (by multiplication) a map $A \to M$. These are mutually inverse just by the usual multiplicativity of determinant.

Comment: Incidentally, from this direct approach using determinants of matrices, it’s easy to see that the fact generalises to work from the hypothesis that $M \oplus A^n \cong A^{n+1}$ for any $n \geq 0$.  This can also of course be seen using Kunneth formulas and exterior powers — but the calculations are much less familiar.

Comment: I actually never thought about a more elementary way to solve this problem, since the exterior power method is what first came to mind and it worked so nicely. I agree with the "pulled out of a hat" aspect, but it's nice to see that it can expressed using less technology. I wonder whether the first person who ever solved this problem did it by matrices or by exterior powers!

Comment: Great solution!

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: that is the approach Weibel presents at the very begenning of his K-Book.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase you're looking for is that of a *stably free* module.  Your question is answered in the affirmative in Keith Conrad's (as always) very helpful notes on stably free modules [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/stablyfree.pdf). In particular, note that it's possible to have $A\oplus M\cong A\oplus A\oplus A$ without having $M\cong A\oplus A$, but this is a minimal counterexample:  If $A\oplus M\cong A\oplus A$, then $A\cong M$.

---

*Below here* is an answer to a different question than the one being asked, which I'm leaving in only because of a comment that it was helpful.

Nope!  Take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $M\oplus A\cong M\cong M\oplus M$, but $M\not\cong A$.

On the other hand, for some classes of rings (e.g., $A=\mathbb{Z}$, and I think Dedekind domains) it's true that you can "cancel" finitely-generated modules in the way that you want (that is, if one of the factors is the ring itself).

Comment: Thanks for using this example. Maybe if I see it often enough I will actually remember it for future reference.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Thank you! I know this conter-example, but pay attention to the fact that I actually request $A\oplus M$ to be isomorphic to the direct (bi)product of the ring, i.e., $A\oplus A$.

Comment: @user58504:  Actually, as it stands.  I've answered the wrong question.  Did you mean $M\oplus A\cong A\oplus A$ or $M\oplus A\cong M\oplus M$?

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you very much, Cam.

Comment: Another beautiful reference I've just found is the first chapter of the book(-in-progress) "Algebraic K-Theory" of Weibel: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook/Kbook.I.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ u&v\end{pmatrix}:A\oplus A\to A\oplus M,
$$ 
with $a,b$ in $A$ and $u,v$ in $M$, be an isomorphism. Let 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}c&f\\ d&g\end{pmatrix}:A\oplus M\to A\oplus A
$$ 
with $c,d$ in $A$ and $f,g:M\to A$, be its inverse. (In this post all maps are $A$-linear.)

It is tedious but straightforward to check that 
$$
av-bu:A\to M
$$ 
and 
$$
cg-df:M\to A
$$ 
are inverse isomorphisms.

Edit. I turned this answer into a community wiki because, as pointed out by user26857, the argument had been described a long time ago by Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine in comments under the accepted answer.