# On isomorphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

$\underline {Background}$: Suppose $X$ is a scheme and $\mathcal F$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$ module.

Suppose we have, $\mathcal {F}\oplus \mathcal {O}_X \cong \oplus_r \mathcal {O}_X$ as sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$ modules.

$\underline {Question}$: Can we say that $\mathcal {F} \cong \oplus_{r-1} \mathcal {O}_X$ ?

$\underline {Attempt}$:I tried to define map on all {$SpecA$} which in turn will define a morphism as follows,

If we denote the isomorphism  $\mathcal {F}\oplus \mathcal {O}_X \cong \oplus_r \mathcal {O}_X$ as $\phi$

then I define $T(specA):\mathcal F(specA)\to \oplus_{r-1}\mathcal O(specA)$ as

$T(specA)(a):=\phi(SpecA)(a,0)$ with the last coordinate omitted

But,I cannot see why this should be injective and surjective?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that $r=2$ the answer is yes. The affine case is discussed at this question: [$M\oplus A \cong A\oplus A$ implies $M\cong A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280180/m-oplus-a-cong-a-oplus-a-implies-m-cong-a), and the proof works just as well for all schemes.

If $r \geq 3$ the answer is *no*. It is enough to consider affine schemes. So we have a ring $R$ and an isomorphism of modules $M \oplus R \cong R^{\oplus r}$, the question is whether $M$ is free of rank $r-1$.

You should be aware of the following definition:

> **Definition.** A projective module $P$ is called *stably free* if $P\oplus R^{\oplus n} \cong R^{\oplus m}$ for some $m,n$.

This is a little more general than what you are asking (the extra parameter $n$) but given any stable free module as above then, $M = P\oplus R^{\oplus n-1}$ will be a counterexample to your question. (Note: your $M$ is necessarily a projective module, so *locally* it is isomorphic to $R^{\oplus r-1}$.)

---

Examples of stably-free modules which are not free are a little hard to come by, but for instance Keith Conrad has a note with an example over the real coordinate ring of the 2-sphere. For more examples see papers of Swan and of Kumar et al. There is some discussion about this at this question on [overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27424/a-ring-such-that-all-projectives-are-stably-free-but-not-all-projectives-are-fre) as well. It mentions the Bass Cancellation theorem, which says that for large enough rank (compared to the Krull dimension of the ring) stably free modules actually are free.

Comment: ,thank you for your answer.I understand that M has to be projective module,but can you explain why locally it is isomorphic to $R^{\oplus r-1}$

Comment: Being projective is equivalent to being locally free. Are you asking why its dimension has to be $r-1$? You can just pass to a closed point where you have an isomorphism of vector spaces, and you have additivity of their dimensions.

Comment: ,if we assume $\mathcal F$ is coherent and {$specA$} be its corresponding cover ,so $\mathcal F(specA)$ is a finitely generated projective $A$ module,then $\mathcal F(specA)$ is locally free $A$ module ,I hope from there one can derive that $\mathcal F$ is a locally free sheaf.Does this make sense?

Comment: @HARRY Yes you can derive that. This is the equivalence between locally free and projective modules. Did you want a reference for the proof? You can find it by scouring the standard set of commutative algebra textbooks I think.

Comment: ,can you give a little hint on "you can just pass to a closed point where you have an isomorphism of vector spaces,"

Comment: @HARRY You know that $M\oplus R = R^{\oplus n}$. Locally $M \cong F$ to a free module $F$. So on an open set $F\oplus R = R^{\oplus n}$. Now you need to know the rank of $F$ is $n-1$. Let $m \subset R$ be a maximal ideal and $R/m = k$ is a field. Then $R^{\oplus n} \otimes_R k = k^{\oplus n}$. In other words the rank is preserved. Then the fact that $dim F = n-1$ is a familiar fact about vector spaces.

Comment: @HARRY You could also just use that commutative rings have invariant basis property, if you are familiar with that.